# antonym for "look forward to"

Tags: single-word-requests

Any single word that means "not to look forward to"? Like "dread" but not as strong, or "dislike" but for something that hasn't happened yet? "She came to _____ the two weeks of a major tournament."

Thanks for all the thought. What a great site. The context, which I should have made clearer, is that she doesn't look forward to a major tournament because she doesn't like tennis and her brother wants to watch every minute of it. The tone should be slightly amusing. "His sister, not yet a tennis player, came to ___ the two weeks of a major tournament." In this context, I think something like @user307254's "despair over" comes the closest.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dread

Comment: Please describe more carefully the emotion you’re trying to pinpoint.

Comment: Probly _fear_ for strong and _worry_ for weaker anxieties about the future. But neither of these refers necessarily to the future like _look forward to_ does. This is one of the `Time` metaphor themes, like 'The Future is Ahead of Us' (the Past is behind us, so we can look back on it). _Fear_ and _worry_ are strictly emotional, but their source is something as yet unexperienced, though it may simply be repetition of past experiences. However, the future is not necessarily implied.

Answer (score 4):

'**Apprehensive**'[1](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apprehensive) or '**Apprehend**'[2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/apprehend) may be the word you're looking for.

E.g. She was **apprehensive** about the next two weeks of the tournament.

Or "She became/came to be **apprehensive** about the coming weeks of the tournament"

Alternatively, "She came to **apprehend** the two weeks of a major tournament"

Though I tend to generally avoid the use of the word in this form as it can easily be misunderstood as the verb of a different definition

Adjective meaning to feel uneasy, anxious or fearful about something.

Comment: Please include the meaning of your suggestion.

Comment: @JJJ Is this sufficient?

Comment: Again, include reference links to dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the antonym of *look forward to* would be **have reservations about**:

> She came to *have reservations about* the two weeks of a major tournament.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of *reservation*:

> **2 b** : DOUBT, MISGIVING
>   // had serious *reservations* about marriage

Of course, **have misgivings about** could also be used.

---

If you need a single word, then:

> She came to **question** the two weeks of a major tournament. OR
>   She came to **doubt** the two weeks of a major tournament.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***anxious***:

> Feeling or showing worry, nervousness, or unease about something with an uncertain outcome.
>   *‘she was extremely **anxious** about her exams’*
>   *‘an **anxious** look’*
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anxious)</sub>

For your usage:

> She was ***anxious*** during the two weeks before a major tournament.

Answer (score 1):

> **Regret**[ ri-gret ]
>
> verb (used with object), re·gret·ted, re·gret·ting.
>
> 1) to feel sorrow or remorse for (an act, fault, disappointment, etc.):
>   He no sooner spoke than he regretted it.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/regret)

"His sister, not yet a tennis player, would come to regret the two weeks of a major tournament."

Answer (score 1):

**[foreboding](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/foreboding)** (Cambridge Dictionary)

> a feeling that something very bad is going to happen soon

She had a strange **foreboding** about the next two weeks of the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 
'***despair***'.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/despair):

***despair***

*intransitive verb*

: to lose all hope or confidence

despair of winning

*transitive verb*

obsolete : to lose hope for

Answer (score 0):

She  came  to  be  apathetic to  the  next  two  weeks  of  her  tournament.

> Apathetic  means having  or  showing  no  interest  about  a thing which  is  going to  happen.

Here is  the link.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apathetic.

Answer (score 0):

> **Reluctance**[ ri-luhk-tuh ns ]
>
> \noun
>
> 1) unwillingness; disinclination.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reluctance)
>
> ———-
>
> **reluctant**[ ri-luhk-tuhnt ]
>
> \adjective
>
> 1) unwilling; disinclined:
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reluctant)

“His sister, not yet a tennis player, is reluctant about the two weeks of a major tournament."

“His sister is reluctant about the two weeks of a major tournament because she is not yet a tennis player ."

“His sister’s reluctance about the two weeks of a major tournament is because she is not yet a tennis player ."

Answer (score 0):

> **Reticent**[ ret-uh-suhnt ]
>
> \adjective
>
> 1) disposed to be silent or not to speak freely; reserved.
>   ￼
>   2) reluctant or restrained.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reticent)
>
> See also reticence

Answer (score -2):

### worry [about]

I was first going to suggest **fear**, but that's almost as far along the spectrum as **dread**.

Edited to add the (pretty obvious, I must say) *about* because of downvotes. It works:

- "She came to *worry about* the two weeks of a major tournament."